# Android Instrumentation test (launch another activity B after button click)

Tags: kotlin, android-espresso, android-instrumentation

I'm trying to perform a simple UI test case: I have 2 activities (A-B).
A has a fragment immediately loaded from the xml file of the activity, all the code is hosted in the fragment, so basically nothing's done inside activity A. Now the idea is to open activity B after the user clicks on a button from the fragment hosted by activity A.

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    binding?.openActivityBtn?.setClickListener {
        requireActivity().startActivity(Intent(requireActivity(),ActivityA::class.java))
        requireActivity().finish()
    }
}
```

Here's my test case: I'm using `ActivityTestRule` since I've never had any issues with it in the past (yes I know it is depreciated):

```
  @get:Rule
var activityRule = ActivityTestRule(ActivityA::class.java, false, false)

 @Before
fun setUp(){
    Intents.init()
    activityRule.launchActivity(Intent())
}

@Test
fun shouldShowEmptyUI(){
    onView(isRoot()).check(noOverlaps())
    onView(withResourceName("some_ui_component")).check(matches(isDisplayed()))
    onView(withResourceName("some_ui_component")).check(matches(isDisplayed()))
    onView(withResourceName("open_activity_btn")).check(matches(isDisplayed()))
    onView(withResourceName("open_activity_btn")).perform(click())
    intended(hasComponent(ComponentName(ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext(), ActivityB::class.java.name)))
}

@After
fun tearDown(){
    Intents.release()
}
```

I have the error:

> androidx.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler$AssertionFailedWithCauseError: Wanted to match 1 intents. Actually matched 0 intents.

> IntentMatcher: has component: has component with: class name: is "com.package.ActivityB" package name: an instance of java.lang.String short class name: an instance of java.lang.String

> Matched intents:[]

I can't really figure out what's going here, any help would be appreciated.